# Алгоритм Боуэр Мура

Tags: c, алгоритм

Как реализовать таблицу сдвигов для алгоритм Боуэр Мура поиска подстроки в строке на С? Можно пример вычисления таблицы или всего поиска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Можно](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html)
Скопирую код сюда, чтобы ответ не состоял из одной ссылки =) Но по ссылке все равно стоит сходить

```
void preBmBc(char *x, int m, int bmBc[]) {
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < ASIZE; ++i)
      bmBc[i] = m;
   for (i = 0; i < m - 1; ++i)
      bmBc[x[i]] = m - i - 1;
}

void suffixes(char *x, int m, int *suff) {
   int f, g, i;

   suff[m - 1] = m;
   g = m - 1;
   for (i = m - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
      if (i > g && suff[i + m - 1 - f] < i - g)
         suff[i] = suff[i + m - 1 - f];
      else {
         if (i < g)
            g = i;
         f = i;
         while (g >= 0 && x[g] == x[g + m - 1 - f])
            --g;
         suff[i] = f - g;
      }
   }
}

void preBmGs(char *x, int m, int bmGs[]) {
   int i, j, suff[XSIZE];

   suffixes(x, m, suff);

   for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
      bmGs[i] = m;
   j = 0;
   for (i = m - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (suff[i] == i + 1)
         for (; j < m - 1 - i; ++j)
            if (bmGs[j] == m)
               bmGs[j] = m - 1 - i;
   for (i = 0; i <= m - 2; ++i)
      bmGs[m - 1 - suff[i]] = m - 1 - i;
}

void BM(char *x, int m, char *y, int n) {
   int i, j, bmGs[XSIZE], bmBc[ASIZE];

   /* Preprocessing */
   preBmGs(x, m, bmGs);
   preBmBc(x, m, bmBc);

   /* Searching */
   j = 0;
   while (j <= n - m) {
      for (i = m - 1; i >= 0 && x[i] == y[i + j]; --i);
      if (i < 0) {
         OUTPUT(j);
         j += bmGs[0];
      }
      else
         j += MAX(bmGs[i], bmBc[y[i + j]] - m + 1 + i);
   }
}
```